# Close request and start asynchronous computation in Java

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous

i'm trying to create an asynchronous servlet, so that the client makes a request, get an answer like "process started" and stops waiting. 
The servlet will start some computation and write the result on a DB and then the user will be able to check if the process is terminated and to see its result.

Well, every time i try to do this a get errors. In the request i have a Connection object, and if i pass it to a Thread and then start it, when the main servlet ends the connection gets closed and the Thread throws an Exception ('connection has already been closed').

Is there a way to just give to the client a response and tell it not to wait anymore while the servlet does all its job?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @chade which code should i share? I'm asking for a way of doing something, not for a solution to an error...

Comment: You can have your client do the asynchronous request, using Ajax or similar technology. When there is a resposne, the callback machanism will be used to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were mentioning a DB Connection, why not create the Connection inner your Thread?

Comment: Because i don't have the password for the connection. I'm working on a big Project for my society with a lot of security issues. It would be nice if there was a way of cloning an already valid connection

Comment: You really need to post more details of your "big project" to get help. Are you using Hibernate? Are you using Spring transaction manager?

Comment: This is the solution I adopted in the end, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There exists **Ajax** (JavaScript) in the browser to place a call, and have success/failed callbacks received later. That would be the most regular way.

If *more is required*, register the request for scheduling in a queue = store something in the database. Then have a **timer task** (for instance from Spring) in your app that does the work. This prevents overloading, DoS.

Comment: i don't need do place the requests in a queue. If i use Ajax, and the user closes its browser, will the servlet still be executed till the end?

Comment: Yes processed till the end (otherwise sometimes undesirable). I meant with "queue," that should the processing take long, simply storing the desired task with its parameters for later, timer based processing would be better.

Answer (score 0):

In fact if looks like the response is fully sent to the client when you close the response output stream (or writer), and you can continue the processing inside the servlet without any threading issues. Unfortunately I could never found a confirmation that if was explicitely allowed in servlet specs, but I could do it successfully in Tomcat (was using version 7)

So provided you note it in a bold comment, your servlet code could look like:

```
void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
    OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
    ...   // generate the output
    out.close();       // the response is sent to client
    // asynchonous processing
    ...
}
```

Comment: What if the client closes the browser after he receives a response? The server probably notes that the socket was closed by client and  kills the process, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, because HTTP is a disconnected protocol.